# Http Connection Pooling in Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Camel as an Orchestration Engine.

```
clients sends HTTP request <-> CAMEL code <---- HTTP Req----- > external
server(s)
```

I am using HTTP4 Component (with default settings) for making HTTP Requests
to external server. I have quite a few http backends.

Right now the way we are making http calls to our backend is as follow:-

```
// The producer is created during app initialisation. This is actually done
via blueprint.xml
ProducerTemplate producer = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();

// Whenever I need to make a http call I am executing the below code with
URL set as something like:- "http4://order-api:8099/orders/v1/ordersearch/"

Exchange exchange = producer.request(URL, new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        log.info("Executing the HTTP request : URL - " + URL + " Headers -
" + headers + " Body : " + body);
        exchange.getIn().setHeaders(headers);
        exchange.getIn().setBody(body);
        }
    });
```

The query I am having is:-

1. Does `HTTP4` in the default setting camel uses some http connection
   pooling while making a call to the external servers?
2. If yes Is there a way I can configure the connection pooling from
   `blueprint.xml`?

I am using `Camel 2.16.1` and the application is deployed in `Karaf 3.0.5`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `http4` component use Apache HttpClient, which support pooling with the use of a `HttpClientConnectionManager`.

By default, camel uses a `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` which is configured with the properties `connectionsPerRoute` and `maxTotalConnections`.

If you want to have more control over this clientConnectionManager, you can provide your own implementation of `org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager`

See [HttpClient connection manager](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html)

Comment: As per http://camel.apache.org/http4.html#HTTP4-HttpComponentOptions%22%3EHttpComponent%20Options `connectionsPerRoute`  & `maxTotalConnections` are having default values 20 & 200. Can you please let me know what is the difference between the two? Let's say I am having 3 http backends `A`,`B` & `C`. Then each will have a max pool of 20 connections totaling to 60? If yes what if I have more than 200 http backends?

Comment: You should look in the Apache HttpClient documentation. `maxTotalConnections` is the total number of connection managed by the pool. In `connectionsPerRoute` a route is not related to camel but to a `HttpRoute` which is a "destination" (host + port + proxy/tunnel). So you're right : which 3 "destinations", you'll have 60 opens connections max by default. You can of course change this default configuration